# Apply a custom function to a large list takes very long time

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, difflib

**Problem:**

I have a list of words of length 48,000 and I am trying to group possible 4 words (if present else lesser) that are closest to each other. I am taking help from the `difflib`  module for this.

I had 2 ways to do this in my mind. Get 4 closest matches using `difflib.get_close_matches()` or make a Cartesian product of the words list and get the scores from each tuple from the product list.

I have a code which works for smaller lists but when the length of the list grows (in my case 48k) , it takes enormous amount of time. I am looking for a scalable solution for this problem.

**Code to reproduce such list:**

```
import random , string , itertools , difflib
from functools import partial
N = 10
random.seed(123)
words = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(5)) for j in range(10)]
```

**My attempts:**

**1:** Created a function which would return the score after creating a Cartesian product. Post this I can group on the first element and take top n as I desire.

```
def fun(x) : return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,*x).ratio()
products = list(itertools.product(words,words))
scores = list(map(fun,products))
```

**2:** A function that directly gives the best n (4) matches

```
f = partial(difflib.get_close_matches , possibilities = words , n=4 , cutoff = 0.4)
matches = list(map(f,words)) #this gives 4 possible matches if presentwords
```

This is also the expected output.

Both works for a small list , but as the size of the list grows , it takes very long time. Hence I tried to resort to Multiprocessing:

**Multiprocessing attempt 1:**

Save the first function (`fun`) in attempt 1 in a py file and then import it

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
import fun
if__name__ == '__main__':
    score_mlt_pr = pool.map(fun.fun, products ) #products is the cartesian product same as attempt 1
scores_mlt = list(score_mlt_pr)
```

**Multiprocessing attempt 2:**

Using the same `f` as attempt 2 earlier but with pool:

```
close_matches = list(pool.map(f,words))
```

With Multiprocessing , the time taken is reduces but is still about 1 hour for a combination of 1000*48000 words.

I hope i could provide a clear example for my problem. Kindly advise how can i speed up my code.

Comment: A very simple optimization is to take advantage of symmetry and replace `itertools.product(words,words)` with `itertools.combinations(words)`. This drops the number of calculations by a little over a factor of 2. However, as long as you're comparing every word to every word, your algorithm will scale as O(n^2). If there are other know facts about the words (e.g. fixed length, ascii only, as in your example), then you can optimize a bit more

Answer (score 1):

This approach would have better performance.

```
words = <wordlist>
res = []
while len(words) > 4:
    # get a word from list
    word=words.pop()
    # Find three closest to it
    closest = difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities=words, n=3, cutoff=0.4)
    #remove found words from list
    for w in closest:
        words.remove(w)
    #add fourth word to list
    closest.append(word)
    res.append(closest)
```

Your methods returns as many 4 word groups as there are words in original list but most likely some of them have same four words. In my method each word is only once in all lists. So with 1000 words you get 250 lists with four words.

I tested your second method with list of 500 words and list of 1000 words. With 500 words it took 1.93796 seconds to run and with 1000 words 7.75168 seconds. So time is growing exponentaly; double N caused almost 4 times slower run.

With my approach list of 500 words took 0.2435 second and list of 1000 words ran 0.94891 seconds. So double N needed only 1.4 x time. This was excepted since there was less iterations (N/4 vs N) and `get_closest_matches` runs probably faster with fewer possibilities.

---- EDIT ----

If need is create dictionary having all words in the list as keys you could do this

```
res = {}
while len(words) > 4:
    # get a word from list
    word=words.pop()
    # Find three closest to it
    closest = difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities=words, n=3, cutoff=0.4)
    #remove found words from list
    for w in closest:
        words.remove(w)
    #add fourth word to list
    closest.append(word)
    #add values to result
    for w in closest:
        res[w] = closest
#If there is some "leftover words", add them to result
for w in words:
    res[w] = words
```

Now res has as many elements in dictionary as there is unique words in the list. Only problem is "data quality". As the list shrinks during iterations there is less and less options for get_closest_match method to find matching words. So last rounds don't find best matches for the word. On the other hand this method is as fast as previous one.

Is result acceptable depends on where you use this data.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, however I would like as many lists as the input. Not N/4 , so the output of my second attempt is what I am looking for but using a faster way. I would then create a dictionary with words as keys and matches as values